# Data remains "loading" in this weather app in flutter but temperature is loaded

Tags: flutter, dart

I made this simple weather app but the temperature loads and no other data is loading. Its for my school project.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:weather/home.dart';
void main()=>runApp(
  MaterialApp(
    title: "Weather App",
    home: Home()
  )
);

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  var temp;
  var description;
  var currently;
  var humidity;
  var windSpeed;
  late TextEditingController location= TextEditingController();
  Future getWeather() async{
    http.Response response= await http.get(Uri.parse("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Cuttack&units=metric&appid=5e749d88f2df02cacc9be6abf8088531"));
    var results=jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(results);
    setState(() {
      this.temp=results['main']['temp'];
      this.description=results['weather'][2]['description'];
      this.currently=results['weather'][0]['main'];
      this.humidity=results['main']['humidity'];
      this.windSpeed=results['wind']['speed'];
    });
  }
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    this.getWeather();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/3,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                  child: Text(
                    "Currently in Boston",
                    style:TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    )
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  temp!=null?temp.toString()+"\u0000":"Loading",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 40,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                  child: Text(
                      currently!=null?currently:"Loading",
                      style:TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      )
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    leading: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.temperatureHalf),
                    title: Text("Temperature"),
                    trailing: Text(temp!=null?temp.toString()+"\u0080":"Loading"),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.cloud),
                    title: Text("Weather"),
                    trailing: Text(description!=null?description.toString():"Loading"),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.sun),
                    title: Text("Humidity"),
                    trailing: Text(humidity!=null?humidity.toString():"Loading"),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.wind),
                    title: Text("Wind Speed"),
                    trailing: Text(windSpeed!=null?windSpeed.toString():"Loading"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It returns only the temperature, but the description and all other aspects seem to be just loading neverendingly, but when i use print it displays all the data but why is not loading in the app.

Answer (score 0):

JSON

```
{
...
    "weather": [{
        "id": 802,
        "main": "Clouds",
        "description": "scattered clouds",
        "icon": "03n"
    }],
...
    "main": {
        "temp": 29.1,
        "feels_like": 35.25,
        "temp_min": 29.1,
        "temp_max": 29.1,
        "pressure": 1003,
        "humidity": 81,
        "sea_level": 1003,
        "grnd_level": 1000
    },
...
    "wind": {
        "speed": 6.42,
        "deg": 193,
        "gust": 12.11
    },
...
}
```

Mapping to state, `['weather'][2]['description']` has wrong index.

```
    setState(() {
      this.temp=results['main']['temp'];
      this.description=results['weather'][0]['description'];
      this.currently=results['weather'][0]['main'];
      this.humidity=results['main']['humidity'];
      this.windSpeed=results['wind']['speed'];
    });
```